# What is the best way to use data in Vue.JS between components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

EveryOne!

I have a front of aplication in Vue.JS in which people are singing in.
with axios.
If login is ok - Vue application gets User Object like this server

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5acf15a9d1bec12bdc4c2243"),
"role" : "admin",
"email" : "dev0@jland.info",
"name": "Pavel"}
```

I want to store this somewhere in Vue.JS but I got a lot of components (.vue) in my project I what to use data  as well in all components throught whole application

Comment: Read this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html (and then probably implement this: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Vuex.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html

It's a plugin you incorporate into your Vue app. It provides global state management so you can share data through your components without losing reactivity.